# How do Dodge and Parry work?

Tags: combat, forbidden-lands

More specifically, I'm confused about when to add weapon damage: if the defender rolls as many 6s as the attacker, does the defender still suffer weapon damage or is the attack neutralized altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, rolling successes equal to the attacker's successes negates the hit.

The rules aren't quite as explicit on this as we might like, but I think it's fairly clear from the descriptions of the Dodge and Parry fast actions (in the Combat chapter).  Both use the same wording to describe the effect of successes on a Dodge/Parry roll:

> Every X you roll eliminates a X from the attacker’s roll.

If you eliminate all of their successes, it stands to reason that the outcome is the same as if the attacker had rolled 0 successes originally (i.e., a miss).

If it was intended that you had to fully eliminate the damage of the hit in order to negate it, it seems like this rule would have been phrased "Every X you roll reduces the damage of the hit by 1" or similar.